# c# Reading xml with namespace problem

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I want to read the value in **rss/channel/itunes:subtitle**

xml: see http://podcast.q-dance.nl/audio/qdance/q-dancepodcast.xml

I tried:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument pd = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
pd.Load(podcasterUrl);
XmlElement resultt = pd.DocumentElement;
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(pd.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("itunes", "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd");
XmlNode nodeS = resultt.SelectSingleNode("/rss/channel/itunes:subtitle", mgr);
string subtitle = nodeS.InnerText.ToString();
```

subtitle is now:

```
This is the official ...
```

but in XML it is

```
Representing the ...
```

**Can someone help me?**

Comment: Using your code I received subtitle as "Representing the harder styles in dance music"

Comment: I checked your code - and i got "representing the harder styles ..." too. perhaps there is a little confusion because of "summary" and "subtitle"?

Comment: ok, the problem was that I used another xml file than in my db. It works!